# Solve $M x =b$ where the column vectors of $M$ and $b$ all have $k$ ones and $n - k$ zeros.

Tags: linear-algebra

Denote $M$ as a $n \times n$ independence (invertible) matrix, whose elements are either 0 or 1. Each column vector of $M$ (e.g., $M$[:,j]) sums to $k$. That is $\sum_j M_{i,j} = k$. In other words, $M$[:,j] has $k$ ones and $n - k$ zeros.

Also we have another vector $b$ whose elements are either 0 or 1 too, and $\sum_j b_j = k$ too.

We want to solve $M x = b$. Can we prove that each element of $x$ (i.e. $x_j$) is either 1, 0, or -1? If yes, how to prove it? If not, can I have an counterexample? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exist counterexamples. Here is one for the case $n=6, k=3$

The solution to

$$Mx=b$$
with
$$M=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&1&0&0}, \ b=\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\0\\0\\0} \ \text{is} \ x=\pmatrix{-1\\ \ \ 2\\ \ \ 1\\-1\\-2\\ \ \ 2}$$

with $\det(M)=-3 \ne 0$.

I haven't found any counterexample in the cases $n<6$.

---

When $\det(M)=0$ (you have ruled out the case), counterexamples are many. For example when $n=4, k=2$ :

$$M=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\1&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1} \ \text{and} \ b=\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0}$$

Then $Mx=b$ has an infinite number of solutions (because $\det(M)=0$) ;

Among them :

$$x=\pmatrix{1/3\\1/3\\1/3\\0}$$

which hasn't its entries in $\{0,1,-1\}$.

**Remark** Oddly, there are not many cases where $\det(M) \ne 0$  : here is, on a simulation basis, the percentage of matrices $M$ with $\det(M) \ne 0$ for all cases $0<p<n<9$ :

$$\begin{array}{l|rrrrrrr}
\text{n\p}&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\hline
2&50.0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
3&22.2&22.2&0&0&0&0&0\\
4& 9.6&22.3& 9.0&0&0&0&0\\
5& 3.7&19.4&19.5& 4.1&0&0&0\\
6& 1.7&15.5&23.9&16.0& 1.5&0&0\\
7& 0.5&12.6&26.0&26.0&14.1& 0.6&0\\
8& 0.2&10.6&27.2&35.1&31.0&12.1& 0.3 \end{array}$$

Approximate proportions (in $\%$, based on a simulation) of invertible matrices $M$ for different values of $n$ and $p$.

Matlab program that has helped me to generate counterexamples, here for the case $m=8; k=3$ :

```
 format rat ; % rational numbers
 n=8;k=3;
 W=[ones(1,k),zeros(1,n-k)]; % prototype of column vector
 rng('shuffle'); % initialization of Random Numbers Gen.
 for a=1:1000 ; % 1000 attempts
    % construction of matrix M, then vector B :
    M=zeros(n);
    for p=1:n
       M(:,p)=W(randperm(n))'; % random permutation
    end;
    B=W(randperm(n))';
    if det(M)~=0
       X=M\B; % solution of MX=B
       im=ismember(X,[-1,0,1]);
       if ~all(im) ; % if not all entries of X are in [-1,0,1]
          det(M),[M,X,B] ; % display
       end;
    end;
 end;
```

Comment: Does your issue finds its origin in graph theory ?

Comment: Thank you! I may not use the proper term, when I say “independent”, I actually mean it is invertible. Is there a way or direction or potential approach to prove it?

Comment: 1) Indeed it is usual to reserve "**independent**" to a column set ("The columns of $M$ are linearly independent") and **invertible** for a matrix. 2) About your question (and this is why I have asked you in which context this question arose) I have the feeling that this issue has to be placed in correspondence with another domain such as graph theory. But how ?

Comment: Actually, I derive it from another linear algebra problem (probably). The original problem is that given a set of column vectors (k ones, n - k zeros), and one more column vectors (also k ones, n - k zeros), what is the minimum column vectors needed to linearly represent the given one?

Comment: May I confirm what does the proportions here mean? Do you explore some portion of invertible matrix given n and p, and have found out the explored ones are all in favor of my hypothesis?

Comment: Oh, thank you for your update! Sorry that my notification failed to work properly.